# Give user option to download all content from Firebase

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, firebase

I am trying to make `function` to let user download all content from **Firebase** before using `application` which is optional. It should make user experience better. Is it possible?

Right now my `JSON` contains these fields. The JSON is actually much longer:

```
  "Snuses" : {
    "Catch Eucalyptus White Large" : {
          "Brand" : "Catch",
          "Products" : "Catch Eucalyptus White Large",
          "PorionWeight" : 21.6,
          "flavor" : "Tobacco, Eucalyptus",
          "nicotine" : 8.0,
          "PortionsCan" : 24,
          "shipping weight" : 39,
          "productUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/snuspedia.appspot.com/o/Catch%20Dry%20Eucalyptus%20White%20Mini.png?alt=media&token=b712f44c-a83b-4a18-b9cc-7f77897e5489"
        },
```

And I use Firebase Storage also, which contains images about (`20mb`). I would like to `parse` all of the info + images and after it is done then show them.

Right now I am doing it like this for images:

```
if productsValue[indexPath.row]["productUrl"] != nil {
            cell.snusProductImageView!.kf_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: productsValue[indexPath.row]["productUrl"] as! String)!)
        }
        else {
            let productImageref = productsValue[indexPath.row]["Products"] as! String

            let decomposedPath = productImageref.decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping

            cell.snusProductImageView.image = nil
            cell.snusProductImageView.kf_showIndicatorWhenLoading = true

            FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("\(decomposedPath).png").downloadURLWithCompletion({(url, error)in

                FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Snuses").child(decomposedPath).child("productUrl").setValue(url!.absoluteString)

                let resource = Resource(downloadURL: url!, cacheKey: decomposedPath)

                cell.snusProductImageView.kf_setImageWithURL(url)

            })
```

And pretty much same for all other content.

What shoult be the best option to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I met a similar problem as you a while ago when I wanted my IOS app to download all the Firebase data before launching so as to improve user performance and my solution was to use a local database to store the data.

Personally I chose Realm because it is easy to implement and use but there are many other available options such as Core Data or SQLite.

However, my solution can only solve half your problem as you have a sizeable amount of images to store as well. I have not yet deal with storing such a big amount of images so I can't give you advice on that. Other than the images, Realm will store the rest of the data for you just fine.

Comment: And my content is updating too.